# How to achieve that chip on card in flutter? I mean chip half overly on card in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How to achieve that chip on card in flutter? I mean chip half overly on card in flutter.

[image]

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet, that you’ve tried so far? And about the image, you can include proper screenshot instead of camera by marking on image.

Comment: I have designed the above-given UI in flutter code... there is no image or code sharing option in the comment. Although I will share the Github link of the code in the comment

Comment: https://github.com/ruqaiyasattar/TODO_UI_Flutter

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using stack, here is an example

and here is the result of that code
[image: Result image]

```
Stack(
    clipBehavior: Clip.none,
    children: [
      const Card(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
          child: SizedBox(
            width: double.maxFinite,
            child: Center(
              child: Text('This is card content'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(
        top: -8,
        left: 16,
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 8,
            vertical: 4,
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.red,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          ),
          child: const Text(
            'TODO',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
    ],
),
```

**Note:**
if your app supports `RTL` & `LTR` locales and want to move that `tag` accordingly, use

```
 PositionedDirectional(
     top: -8,
     start: 16,
     child: ...
```

instead of

```
Positioned(
     top: -8,
     left: 16,
     child: ...
```

Comment: what is kPadding?

Comment: Ooh sorry, used my consts, I set it to 16.0, will update the answer